# laravel elasticsearch search and paginate result

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, search

I installed Elasticsearch in laravel and need to get more than 10 result and paginate them. I am not able to get what should be code in laravel to get the desired result. below is my Post request Code

```
Route::post('search', 'Api\ProductController@search');
```

Search Post request Code:

```
  public function search(Request $request){
      
      $searchresult =  Product::search($request->input('search'))->get();
      return $searchresult;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Elasticquent](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent#search-collections) (Elasticsearch for Eloquent Laravel Models), In order to get more than 10 results (which is the default in elasticsearch)
you can use the **Query Based Search** function:

`public static function searchByQuery($query = null, $aggregations = null, $sourceFields = null, $limit = null, $offset = null, $sort = null)`

The `$limit` parameter is the one you are looking for (Number of records to return).

Comment: I am looking to all search result and use paginate to show them in app as customer scrolls down. I am stuck at point on how to get more than 10 result and paginate

Comment: I am able to increase result from 10 but still stuck at pagination

Comment: By default, searches return the top 10 matching hits. To page through a larger set of results, you can use the search API's from and size parameters. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/paginate-search-results.html.  add `"from" => 0` to your `body`

Comment: yes, I was reviewing that page, I had 1 query in it. "The API returns a PIT ID.". This PIT ID is common for all users or i have to implement this for each user

Comment: If you use one common PIT ID then you will have to extend its `keep_alive` time. you should know that open point-in-times prevent the old segments from being deleted since they are still in use meaning that more disk space and file handles are needed.

Comment: @chetan suri https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I am able to increase result from 10 to whatever i want in 'size' field. I am still stuck as to how I can paginate so user can scroll result in app and more results are shown similar to normal pagination

```
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

          $params = $client->search([  
          "index"=> "products",
          
          "type" => "App\\Models\\Product",
          
          'body' => [
            "size" => 100,
              'query'=> [
                  'match'=>[
                      'name' => $request->input('search'),                       
                  ]
              ]
          ]
        ]);

        $result = $params['hits']['hits'];
       return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the from and to as they suggest in the query to paginate. You have to move both the numbers for every page.

```
GET /_search
{
  "from": 5,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user.id": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

`By default, you cannot use from and size to page through more than 10,000 hits`

See if this package helps - https://github.com/rtamizh/laravel-es ( promotion for my own library though :) ). Here you can either use scroll or from function to get what you want